# Block SMTP by iptables except locally

Tags: iptables, smtp

Can you help me with iptables. I want to allow send emails locally on server, and forbid to send anywhere else. i made some changes in iptables, but without success.
I have CentOS. Only rule that works

```
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 25,465,587 -j DROP
```

But it blocks all SMTP traffic.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport ! -o lo --dport 25,465,587 -j DROP
```